# Properly use the show element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 css buttons, 1 on top of the post and 2 on bottom. I want to keep the bottom buttons hidden. If a user clicks on the top button he will be navigated to the bottom button and bottom button will become visible. But cant seem to make it work as expected.

Here's what I tried...

```js
function showbtn() {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Awesome button css Start */
.btn-margin {
margin-top: 1.6rem;
box-sizing: inherit;
text-align: center;
}
.btn {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
box-sizing: inherit;
color: white !important;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
line-height: 42px;
pointer-events: all;
position: relative;
text-decoration-line: none;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 1.6em;
padding: 0 2em;
transition: 800ms ease all;
}
.btn-green {
background-color: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn-green:hover {
background-color: #fff;
color: #1AAB8A !important;
}
.btn-blue {
background-color: #0abced;
}
.btn-blue:hover {
background-color: #fff;
color: #0abced !important;
}
.btn:before,.btn:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
height: 2px;
width: 0;
transition: 400ms ease all;
}
.btn:after {
right: inherit;
top: inherit;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
.btn-green:before,.btn-green:after {
background: #1AAB8A;
}
.btn-blue:before,.btn-blue:after {
background: #0abced;
}
.btn:hover:before,.btn:hover:after {
width: 100%;
transition: 800ms ease all;
}
/* Awesome button css End */
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="#btn" onclick="showbtn()">
Click Here To See
</a></div>
<br>
<br>
................Content................
<br>
<br>
<div id="btn">
<div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="https://examplelink.com">
Click Here To See 1
</a></div>
<div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="https://examplelink.com">
Click Here To See 2
</a></div>
</div>
```

Internal linking seems to work. But showing/hiding element isn't working for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: *I have two css buttons*....you have 3 buttons not 2!!!

Comment: Sorry for that. I meant 2 set of buttons.. Edited @Mamun

Comment: it work just well for me :/ (despite the 2 buttons are visible at start)

Comment: but your code is working as you expected. it shows/hides the bottom 2 buttons when you click the top button

Comment: Instead of compilind css withing your javascript code try to use bootstrap native classes. Try to toggle the class `d-none` (hides the element), and/or `d-block` (shows the element). So in js you work out the logic, and leave the css to completely manage the style of your elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the second buttons group by default using `display:none` and just show it on click.

```js
function showbtn() {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn");
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Awesome button css Start */

.btn-margin {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0 3px 3px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0 1px 7px 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 1px -1px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 42px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}

.btn-green {
  background-color: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #1AAB8A !important;
}

.btn-blue {
  background-color: #0abced;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0abced !important;
}

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  transition: 400ms ease all;
}

.btn:after {
  right: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-green:before,
.btn-green:after {
  background: #1AAB8A;
}

.btn-blue:before,
.btn-blue:after {
  background: #0abced;
}

.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 800ms ease all;
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}


/* Awesome button css End */
```

```html
<div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="#btn" onclick="showbtn()">
Click Here To See
</a></div>
<br>
<br> ................Content................
<br>
<br>
<div id="btn">
  <div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="https://examplelink.com">
Click Here To See 1
</a></div>
  <div class="btn-margin"><a class="btn btn-green" href="https://examplelink.com">
Click Here To See 2
</a></div>
</div>
```